# Can address value of a static variable match with a heap allocated address?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, static, heap-memory

Some snippets of the code I have is below

```
static const int s_kVar1 = 0;
static const int s_kVar2 = 1;

...

void foo()
{
    MyObject *o = new MyObject();
    // Is it ever possible that (o == &s_kVar1) or (o == &s_kVar2)
}
```

Comment: Your question seems to ask `o == &s_kVar1`, but the code asks `&o == &s_kVar1`.

Comment: Your syntax is invalid for `o`, since the heap needs a pointer.

Comment: Have you encountered something that makes you believe this or is this purely hypothetical?

Comment: Btw I do not think you understand what `static` mean in this context. And if  constness of those variable matters.

Comment: `o` and `&s_kVar1` are pointers to different types and therefore are not comparable.  If you say `o == (MyObject*)&s_kVar1`, that could compare equal on a system with different-size pointers depending on type.

Comment: @RaymondChen I think this is unnecessary verbalism, OP wants to know it that addresses can be equal, this is not a question of valid syntax. They both can be converted to `void *`. And I do not think converting `int *` to `MyObject *` is legal

Comment: @Slava OPs code says `o == &s_kVar1` (in a comment) which is non valid syntax

Comment: @tobi303 to be pedantic that is not a code, but comment to show the idea

Comment: @Slava to be super pedantic ;) this idea is wrong because `o` and `&s_kVar1` cannot be compared like this correctly

Comment: @tobi303 how about `static_cast<const void *>( o ) == static_cast<const void *>( &s_kVar1 )` or `const char *`

Comment: @Slava that would be fine, the thing is just that `o == &s_kVar1` may happen to be true and for a not so strict interpretation of the question in the title the answer may even be yes. What the OP really wants to know only OP can clarify.

Comment: @tobi303 I think subject of the question clearly says that OP want to know if address can be the same, he just does not know how to express that in code properly. OP if that the case replace `MyObject *` with `int *` and that would eliminate a lot of questions

Comment: I think 'static' is misleading here. The reason s_kVar1 will go into the static memory is 'const' - so it's not supposed to change. The keyword 'static' here means internal linkage - s_kVar1 won't be included into the export table.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edit @Slava This is the code/question I intended to ask.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is NO. Different objects are guaranteed to have different addresses. Global (s_kVar) and dynamically allocated objects (o) go in different memory regions.

P.S. But yes, you can abuse the language to break that guarantee. You can construct two different objects in the same memory location.

Comment: @MadPhysicist only one member of an union can be active at a time.

Answer (score 0):

No. Static variables are stored in .BSS or .DATA segments depending on whether they are initialized or uninitialized(0 initialized). In your case,

static const int s_kVar1 = 0; will go in .BSS and
static const int s_kVar2 = 1; will go in .DATA

Heap is for dynamic allocations.

BTW i don't see why you use static const at file scope . const makes internal linkage by default and global variables have static lifetime. Unless of course you're using C where i can see it being useful.